# Use variable value within a Json call

Tags: javascript, json, variables

This is my json info.

```
{"RAW":<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{"CAN":<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{"AUD":     {"FROMSYMBOL":"CAN","BUY":"0.317993","SELL":"0.31012","MARKETCAP":"12,787,119","CHANGE":"2.13%"}}

"RISE":
    {"AUD":
        {"FROMSYMBOL":"RISE","BUY":"0.337224","SELL":"0.331142","MARKETCAP":"13,396,190","CHANGE":"0.00%"}}

"SAFEX":
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{"AUD":
{"FROMSYMBOL":"SAFEX","BUY":"0.013389","SELL":"0.013389","MARKETCAP":"29,777,352","CHANGE":"0.00%"}}

"HST":
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{"AUD":{"FROMSYMBOL":"HST","BUY":"1.00726","SELL":"0.980698","MARKETCAP":"30,587,338","CHANGE":"9.66%"}}

"HAV":<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;{"AUD":
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{"FROMSYMBOL":"HAV","BUY":"0.601209","SELL":"0.495748","MARKETCAP":"32,375,759","CHANGE":"3.38%"}}
```

This is my code.

```
The CAN page = 

    document.getElementById("CAN-PRICE").innerHTML = jsonObj.RAW.CAN.AUD.BUY;

The RISE page =

    document.getElementById("RISE-PRICE").innerHTML = jsonObj.RAW.RISE.AUD.BUY;
```

I don't want to create a specific page for each one.

What i can do is pull a specific variable value for example

```
 var foo = "SAFEX";
```

what i want to be able to do is insert that value into the json call for like this.

```
 document.getElementById("foo-PRICE").innerHTML = jsonObj.RAW.foo.AUD.BUY;
```

I have tried about everything i can think of eval() seems to do nothing no matter how i chop it up.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(foo +"-PRICE").innerHTML = jsonObj.RAW[foo].AUD.BUY;
```